# How to efficiently store and manipulate sparse binary matrices in Octave?

Tags: matrix, octave, sparse-matrix, binary-matrix

I'm trying to manipulate sparse *binary* matrices in GNU Octave, and it's using way more memory than I expect, and relevant sparse-matrix functions don't behave the way I want them to.  I see [this question about higher-than-expected sparse-matrix storage in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357626/matlab-allocates-a-sparse-matrix-more-memory-than-is-required), which suggests that this matrix should consume *even more* memory, but helped explain (only) part of this situation.

For a sparse, binary matrix, I can't figure out any way to get Octave to *NOT STORE* the array of values (they're always implicitly `1`, so need not be stored). **Can this be done?** Octave always seems to consume memory for a values array.

A trimmed-down example demonstrating the situation: create random sparse matrix, turn it into "binary":

```
mys=spones(sprandn(1024,1024,.03)); nnz(mys), whos mys
```

Shows the situation. The consumed size is consistent with the storage mechanism outlined in [aforementioned SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20357975/3562032) and expanded below, if `spones()` creates an array of storage-class `double` and if all indices are 32-bit (i.e.,

```
TotalStorageSize - rowIndices - columnIndices == NumNonZero*sizeof(double)
```

-- unnecessarily storing these values (all `1`s as `double`s) is over half of the total memory consumed by this 3%-sparse object.

After messing with this (for too long) while composing this question, I discovered some partial workarounds, so I'm going to "self-answer" (only) part of the question for continuity (hopefully), but I didn't figure out an adequate answer to main question:

**How do I create an efficiently-stored ("no-/implicit-values") binary matrix in Octave?**

*Additional background on storage format follows...*

The Octave docs say the [storage format for sparse matrices](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Storage-of-Sparse-Matrices.html) uses format [Compressed Sparse Column (CSC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_column_.28CSC_or_CCS.29). This seems to imply storing the following arrays (expanding on [aforementioned SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20357975/3562032), with canonical [Yale format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Yale_format) `labels` and tweaks for [column-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order)):

- **values** (`A`), number-of-nonzeros (NNZ) entries of storage-class size;
- **row numbers** (`IA`), NNZ entries of index size (hopefully `int64` but maybe `int32`);
- **start of each column** (`JA`), number-of-columns-plus-1 entries of index size)

In this case, for binary-only storage, I hope there's a way to completely avoid storing array (`A`), but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: As noted above, as I was composing this question, I discovered a workaround to reduce memory usage, so I'm "self-answering" part of this here, but it still isn't fully satisfying, so I'm still listening for a better *actual* answer to storage of a sparse binary matrix without a trivial, bloated, unnecessary values array...

To get a binary-like value out of a number-like value and *reduce* the memory usage in this case, use "logical" storage, created by `logical(X)`. For example, building from above,

```
logicalmys = logical(mys);
```

creates a `sparse bool matrix`, that takes up less memory (1-byte `logical` rather than 8-byte `double` for the values array).

Adding more information to the `whos` information using `whos_line_format` helps illuminate the situation: The default string includes 5 of the 7 properties ([see docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Status-of-Variables.html) for more). I'm using the format string

```
whos_line_format(" %a:4; %ln:6; %cs:16:6:1; %rb:12; %lc:8; %e:10; %t:20;\n")
```

to add display of "elements", and "type" (which is distinct from "class").

With that, `whos mys logicalmys` shows something like

```
 Attr Name            Size      Bytes Class      Elements                 Type
 ==== ====            ====      ===== =====      ========                 ==== 
      mys          1024x1024   391100 double        32250        sparse matrix
      logicalmys   1024x1024   165350 logical       32250   sparse bool matrix
```

So this shows a distinction between `sparse matrix` and `sparse bool matrix`.  However, the total memory consumed by `logicalmys` is consistent with actually storing an array of NNZ booleans (1-byte) -- That is:

- totalMemory minus rowIndices minus columnOffsets leaves NNZ bytes left;

in numbers,

- `165350 - 32250*4 - 1025*4 == 32250`.

So we're still storing 32250 elements, all of which are `1`.  Further, if you set one of the `1`-elements to zero, it reduces the reported storage!  For a good time, try: pick a nonzero element, e.g., `(42,1)`, then zero it: `logicalmys(42,1) = 0;` then `whos` it!

My hope is that this is correct, and that this clarifies some things for those who might be interested.  Comments, corrections, or actual answers welcome!